# Filtering query in elastic search for nested model

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to elastic search and I have to do filter based on following condition.

Filter:

```
FirstName : 
Abc
noName
```

My schema looks like below:

```
{  
   Id:123,
   Name:{  
      FirstName:"abc",
      LastName:"xyz"
   }
},
{  
   Id:1234
},
{  
   Id:1235,
   Name:{  
      FirstName:"yuiy",
      LastName:"poi"
   }
}
```

Some of mine data has Name model added but some of them does not. And I want to filter a data based on FirstName should be "Abc" or Name Field should not exist.

So if i filter using above filter criteria it should give me 123 and 1234 Ids document result.

So how Can I write elastic search query for this? I am connecting using Nest with Asp.Net Mvc.

So if someone can provide me Nest query or Elastic Search query that would be helpful.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @RussCam Yes Exist query helped me.